# Cannot convert System.Object to System.Version at version comparison

Tags: powershell, casting, object-comparison

I'm reading two MS Word files and need to compare the docx properties.

I get the correct output for each variable, but once I compare them it throws me the below error.

Any idea why?

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
1      0      -1     -1
1      1      -1     -1
```

> Could not compare "1.0" to " 1.1". Error: "Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to
>   type "System.Version"."
>   At C:\Users\Sebastian\Documents\IT Projects\Saberwal\Groups - Advanced.ps1:76 char:6
>   +  if ($CurrentVersion -lt $NewVersion) {Write-Output "New is bigger"}
>   +      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComparisonFailure

**Code:**

```
 $CurrentVersion = Check-Version $CurrentSignaturePath $CurrentSignatureFile 
 $NewVersion = Check-Version $NewSignaturePath $NewSignatureFile 
 Write-Output $CurrentVersion
 Write-Output $NewVersion

 if ($CurrentVersion -lt $NewVersion) { Write-Output "New is bigger" }
```

Comment: At which line of your code sample does the error occur? Take a look at [mcve]

Comment: The error occurs at the If statement when I compare the two versions. Strange thing is if I just convert two string variables and compare them it works, but for some reason the returned string from the function acts weird. I use this code as function https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/08/02/use-powershell-to-find-specific-word-built-in-properties/

Answer (score 1):

OK, found a way of doing it.

```
[version]$CurrentVersion = [string]$CurrentVersion
[version]$NewVersion = [string]$NewVersion
```

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[Version] $CurrentVersion = Check-Version $CurrentSignaturePath 
[Version] $CurrentSignatureFile $NewVersion = Check-Version $NewSignaturePath $NewSignatureFile
```

If just tried comparing two versions with `-lt` and it worked fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Tried it already but it doesn't work. Strange thing is if I just convert two string variables and compare them it works, but for some reason the returned string from the function acts weird. I use this code as function https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/08/02/use-powershell-to-find-specific-word-built-in-properties/